# Finding gaps in a table of IP address blocks

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table containing the following fields and sample data in **SQL Server 2005**:

`id          block              block_start block_end  size
523         10.211.15.16/28    0x0AD30F10  0x0AD30F1F 16
531         10.211.15.36/30    0x0AD30F24  0x0AD30F27 4
532         10.211.15.40/29    0x0AD30F28  0x0AD30F2F 8
533         10.211.15.48/29    0x0AD30F30  0x0AD30F37 8
525         10.211.15.72/29    0x0AD30F48  0x0AD30F4F 8`

id is an INT identity column.  block is VARCHAR(18) representing the IP block in CIDR format.  block_start and block_end are BINARY(4) and represent the first and last IPv4 address in the block, respectively.  The size is the number of IP addresses in the block.

With a given range of IPs and number of IPs as input, I need a way to query for the first available gap.  For example, I might want to find the first missing gap of **4** IP addresses between **10.211.15.16** and **10.211.15.80**.  In this example, the correct output should be 10.211.15.32/30 (0x0AD30F20 through 0x0AD30F23).  If I wanted the first gap of **8** IP address in the same range, the correct output should be 10.211.15.56/29 (0x0AD30F38 through 0x0AD30F3F).

The output being in CIDR (varchar) or binary format is not an issue as I have functions that can easily convert between the two, but I imagine the querying will need to be done against the binary fields.

If necessary, I can leverage application logic (Java or ColdFusion), but I would rather not if I can help it.

Added sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d45ad

Comment: can you add sqlfiddle please

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d45ad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the gap by using `lead()` and converting the block fields to integers.  Something like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             cast(lead(block_start) over (order by block_start) as bigint) as nextstart,
             cast(block_end as bigint) as thisend
      from iptable t
     ) t
where nextstart - thisend - 1 > @MYNUMBEROFIPS;
```

If you want to use range comparisons on block, just be very careful.  You should convert the block to a numeric value before doing the comparison.

EDIT:

You can get the equivalent functionality by doing:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, cast(block_end as bigint) as thisend,
             (select top 1 cast(block_start as bigint)
              from iptable t2
              where t2.block_start > t.block_start
              order by t2.block_start
             ) as nextstart
      from iptable t
     ) t
where nextstart - thisend - 1 > @MYNUMBEROFIPS;
```

Comment: I failed to mention that this is SQL Server 2005 and lead() is not available in that version.  Additionally, wouldn't converting to integer cause problems at the edge of the octets since the integer range for octets is 0-255?

Comment: Thank you, @gordon-linoff.  Your edit pretty much gets me all the way there.  I have to make a few small tweaks:

1) The final WHERE clause should be `>=` to make sure it gets gaps matching exactly the number of IPs

2) To find gaps in a subset, I have to add conditions to the t2 subquery narrowing down the blocks like so:

`where t2.block_start > t.block_start and t.block_start > @MYBLOCKSTART and t.block_end < @MYBLOCKEND`